# Mysql query for autocomplete suggest from two column?

Tags: php, mysql, autocomplete

I have a table structure as follows.

For jquery autocomplete, user will give input as either by `Emp_Name` or by `Emp_Id`.

Suggestion should be in format `Emp_Name` | `Emp_Id` as label on select.

I want to use `Emp_Id` as value *but* i still want to show `Emp_Name` in textbox and `Emp_Id` should be hidden.

Is this possible?

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `Emp_Name` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `Emp_Id` varchar(6) default NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `employee`
--

INSERT INTO `employee` (`Emp_Name`, `Emp_Id`) VALUES
('JOHN', 'E001'),
('JACK', 'E002'),
('MICHAEL', 'E003'),
('LAURA', 'E004');
```

autocomplete.php

```
 <?php
    include 'dbConfig.php';
    $Txt = $_GET['term'];

  if (isset($Txt)){
    $dbArray = array();
    $Txt=mysql_real_escape_string($Txt);
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM employee WHERE Emp_Name like '$Txt%' OR 
    Emp_Id like '$Txt%' LIMIT 15");

    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $dbArray[] =array('value'=>$rows['Emp_Id'],
                   'label'=>$rows['Emp_Name']. " | ". $rows['Emp_Id']);
        }
    echo json_encode($dbArray);
}


?>
```

Comment: It is possible. I'm a bit confused, is your code working and you're asking for a second opinion or you need some help to make it work?

Comment: it is working.. but in textbox i want to show 'Emp_Name' ..instead 'Emp_Id'  but still value shuld be 'Emp_Id'.. using i want to fetch another records..

Comment: So you are trying to represent the data in the frontend. Could you show your frontend code? as the back end seems to work.

Comment: **Edit:** also user input with  Emp_Id is not working...

Comment: The query should be "SELECT*FROM employee WHERE Emp_Name like '$Txt%' OR 
    Emp_Id = $Txt LIMIT 15"